# Springsource Tool Suite ignores all breakpoints in AspectJ

Tags: eclipse, spring, aspectj

I've tried two versions of STS 3.4.0 and 3.6.2, both versions ignore breakpoints in the AspectJ.

Eclipse AspectJ Development Tools have been installed

```
Version: 2.2.4.e44x-20140918-1700
AspectJ version: 1.8.3.20140820082000
```

Comment: And are the tools enabled for the project or is the project an AspectJ project?

Comment: Are you running the debug as an AspectJ/Java Application?

Comment: Are you by any chance putting breakpoints in around advice? If you are I'd recommend turning off advice inlining (see project properties) and see if that helps.

Comment: yes, I've tried to set a break point inside @around advice, it doesn't work. But I have a workaround - move body to some private method and all breakpoints work fine in this private method. So, I have to use two methods in case I need breakpoints in the Aspect.